# Subtract two dates to get the hourly difference

Tags: excel, vba, date

Given two YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM dates formatted from a string I want to get the time difference in hours between the dates.

This is the code I have:

```
Dim ds1 As String: ds1 = "March 3, 2015 2:00pm " 
Dim ds2 As String: ds2 = "March 4, 2015 3:00pm " '25 hours difference 

ds1 = Format(ds1, "YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM") '2015-03-03-14:00
ds2 = Format(ds2, "YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM") '2015-03-04-15:00

Dim d As Date: d = CDate(ds2) - CDate(ds1) 'gives the 25 hour diffrence
```

The code gives a 'Type Mismatch' error on CDate(ds2) and CDate(ds1) since CDate only works on dates and not hours/minutes.

How can I get the hour difference between these dates?

Comment: CDate works on dates, hours, and minutes. You get a Type Mismatch error because `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM` is not a datetime format that CDate recognizes. Add `Debug.Print IsDate(ds1)` to your code to verify.  If the data is handed to you in that format, you need to parse it as a text string into a format the CDate can recognize. If you are converting a date time to that format, calculate the hours first, then format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A time interval is not a date, so your variable `d` should not be of the `Date` type. As you want a number of hours, it should be an numerical data type, like `Long`.

For difference in hours, you can use the  [`DateDiff`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) function, providing it the unit you want to count the difference by:

```
Dim ds1 As String
Dim ds2 As String
Dim d As Long

ds1 = "2015-03-03 14:00"
ds2 = "2015-03-04 15:00"

d = DateDiff("h", CDate(ds1), CDate(ds2))

Debug.Print d ' outputs 25
```

## Remarks

The `Format` of a date will only work when the argument can be converted to a date, so you might as well perform `CDate` immediately on the original string.

If you can choose the format, then the `"2015-03-03 14:00"` format has the preference (without hyphen between the date and time parts). On my set-up the conversion fails if there is a hyphen there.

Comment: The format lines will need to be removed as it puts it into a string that Excel cannot parse to a date or the `-` between the date and the time needs to be removed.

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives 24 as the answer instead of 25. If I change the second date to 8pm or 10pm it still gives 24

Comment: @BDillan if you put Debug.Print d right after it give 25, at least for me.  What are you doing with d.

Comment: 25 also for me. Note that your date should be formatted without the hyphen before the hour: like `"2015-03-03 14:00"`.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok it didn't work because I had a hyphen between the hours/minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use DateDiff method

```
 Sub test()
   Dim ds1 As String: ds1 = "March 3, 2015 2:00pm "
   Dim ds2 As String: ds2 = "March 4, 2015 3:00pm " '25 hours difference

   ds1 = Format(ds1, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM") '2015-03-03-14:00
   ds2 = Format(ds2, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM") '2015-03-04-15:00

   Dim d As Date: d = CDate(ds2) - CDate(ds1) 'gives the 25 hour diffrence
   youranswer = DateDiff("h", ds1, ds2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the info: if you subtract *real* Dates, that will return a diff in days. Multiply by 24 (since there are 24 hours in a day) and you get the diff in hours.
e.g;

`Print (#03-04-2015 15:00# - #03-03-2015 14:00#) *24`  returns 24.9999999999418